Can't see Tor service is connected or not
I installed tor and enable and start the service.
Now I want to see if tor is connected or not. And I use this command to see the connection progress.
sudo tail -f /var/log/tor/log
But I get this error:
tail: cannot open '/var/log/tor/log' for reading: No such file or directory tail: no files remaining
What did I wrong and how can I see if tor is connected or not?
Thanks.

from man 1 tail:
       -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
              output appended data as the file grows;

              an absent option argument means 'descriptor'

       -F     same as --follow=name --retry

       --retry
              keep trying to open a file if it is inaccessible

so if the logfile is not yet created when you start your tail invocation, use tail -F (capital F) to follow the file (once it is created)
